# Argument passed to call that takes no arguments error for Structs within Structs

Tags: arrays, json, swift, encodable

Hi all so I need to call a function that takes in the following parameters:

```
 let params = [
                "inputParameters" : ["A2":"a1","B1":"b1","C1":"c1","D1":"d1"]
            ]
```

so I made the following encodable struct for it

```
 struct Parameters2 : Encodable{

             let inputparameters = inputParameters(A1: "", B1: "", C1: "", D1: "")
            }

 struct inputParameters: Encodable {

                let A1: String
                let B1: String
                let C1: String
                let D1: String
            }
```

However when I call

```
guard let params = Parameters2(inputParameters(A1:"something", B1:"something", C1:"something", D1:"something"))
            else{
                return
            }
```

I get an error 'Argument passed to call that takes no arguments' even though I clearly defined the input arguments in the struct. Can anyone figure out what could be going wrong?

EDIT: Upon @vadian's suggestions I'm adding the function where this parameter is plugged into:

```
            func executePost(parameters: Parameters2, completion: @escaping (Any?, Error?) -> Void) {
            AF.request("myURL",
                       method: .post,
                       parameters: parameters,
                       encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default, headers: headers).response { response in
                debug print(response)
                
                
                if let error = response.error {
                    completion(nil, error)
                }
                else if let jsonArray = response.value as? Any{
                    completion(jsonArray, nil)
                }
                else if let jsonDict = response.value as? Any{
                    completion([jsonDict], nil )
                }
                
            }}
```

And I call the function as follows:

```
  executePost(parameters: JSONEncoder().encode(params)) { (json, error) in <-- error Cannot convert value of type 'Data' to expected argument type '[String : InputParameters]'
                if let error = error{
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    
                }
                else if let json = json {

                    print(json)
                   
                }
            }
```

Comment: `let inputparameters = inputParameters(A1: ""...` -> `let inputparameters = inputParameters`? But class/struct names should start with an uppercase.

Comment: @Larme I tried that. But when I do that it says Parameters2 doesn't conform to 'Encodable' anymore :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't work for several reasons:

- A key mismatch `inputParameters` (dictionary key) vs. `inputparameters` (struct member).
- The mentioned error which occurs because you assigned a default value in `Parameters2`.
- `guard let` expects an optional, but there is none.

An easier way is one struct

```
struct InputParameters: Encodable {
      let A1, B1, C1, D1: String
}
```

and a literal dictionary key

```
let params = ["inputParameters": InputParameters(A1:"something", B1:"something", C1:"something", D1:"something")]
```

and encode `params`

Comment: I see. Interesting. So when you ask to encode 'params' do you mean to define another struct foe 'params'?

Comment: No. Just `let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(params)`

Comment: Gotchu. However my functoin requires the input to conform to encodable as follows: func execute(parameters: Parameters2) and I previously had Parameters2 conform to encodable. How would I manage that if I use JSONEncoder(). Am I able to explain what I'm trying to say? :/ Sorry I'm still learning these topics.

Comment: Because even when I use JSONEncoder I get 'Cannot convert value of type 'Data' to expected argument type 'Parameters2''

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code how you encode the object.

Comment: Just updated the question with the function that takes in 'params'

Comment: Replace `parameters: Parameters2` with  `parameters: [String: InputParameters]`

Comment: Okay, that eliminates the error form the function but when calling it by using JSONEncode I still have the error 'Cannot convert value of type 'Data' to expected argument type '[String : InputParameters]''  near '.encode(params)'

Comment: cuz when I use 'try' next to JSONEnocder, my button that executes the function throws error 'Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '() throws -> Void' to non-throwing function type '() -> Void''

Comment: No, AF encodes the parameters implicitly. Call the method `executePost(parameters: params)`

Comment: Yes, that works. Thanks, man! Appreciate the help. Now I'm back to my trouble of parsing Json and hopefully, I can figure that out lol.

Comment: Decode the stuff with `responseDecodable`.

Comment: Holy cow how I did miss that in the docs. Real quick: would my Response type be 'String' or 'encodable'? I'm kinda confused on the docs response type references. Regardless, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Hmmm interesting. Looks like I need to create a struct for the kind of data I'm expecting in the response and them set that as the Decodable type.

Comment: Hey @vadian, I was able to get the struct and everythingworking however everytime I decode it, it returns nil. For some reason my jsonData is being shown as ' XXbytes' when I parse it as Data. Do you think you'd be able to help me privately with this?

Comment: Please ask a new question and show the relevant information.

Comment: I asked it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75142639/jsondecoder-returning-nil-while-parsing

Comment: Why do you ask two almost identical questions? I suggested a solution in your other question.